# Return only numeric values from column in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I got requirement of comparing two records:
my table is like;

```
EmpNo payband              ContractType
123   band 4               permanent
124   band 4               contract
125   band 3               permanent
125   band 4               permanent
125   band 5 reviewbody    permanent
```

Now I want to filter duplicate records,my first condition is ContractType='permanent' and then filter by high band. In the above table `EmpNo 125` is one employee and same contractType I want filter his record by high payband. Got some mess in `payband column`

I want Output like:

```
EmpNo payband   ContractType
123   band 4    permanent
125   band 5    permanent
```

any help? thanks

Comment: post the output what you want ??

Comment: my query is showing any result for you or any modifications needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added logic that if there is no numeric value then any first band will come in output:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      EmpNo INT ,
      payband NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      ContractType NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 123, 'band 4', 'permanent' ),
        ( 124, 'band 4', 'contract' ),
        ( 125, 'band 3', 'permanent' ),
        ( 125, 'band 4 review body', 'permanent' ),
        ( 128, 'band', 'permanent' );

WITH    cte1
          AS ( SELECT   EmpNo ,
                        payband ,
                        ContractType ,
                        PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', payband) AS pi ,
                        CHARINDEX(' ', payband, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', payband)) AS ci
               FROM     @t
               WHERE    ContractType = 'permanent'
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY EmpNo ORDER BY CASE
                                                              WHEN pi > 0
                                                              THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(payband,
                                                              pi, ABS(pi - ci)) AS INT)
                                                              ELSE 0
                                                              END DESC ) AS rn
               FROM     cte1
             )
    SELECT  EmpNo ,
            payband ,
            ContractType
    FROM    cte2
    WHERE   rn = 1
```

Output:

```
EmpNo   payband             ContractType
123     band 4              permanent
125     band 4 review body  permanent
128     band                permanent
```

Comment: @ Giorgi Nakeuri, I think your code is correct but i got some mess in 'payband column' for ex: band 4 review body. when I replaced your code in 'band 4' to for emp 125 last record to 'band 4 review body' its not coming. any help?

Comment: You should correct your question if such data is possible. My question. What if I have `'band 4 review body 5 review header'` ?

Comment: updated above query, in that column only band 4 or band 5 etc. no two bands mentioned. Thanks